# Не отрисовывается круг Java

Tags: java, swing

Рисую круг, который должен рандомно кататься по полю. А он не отрисовывается, хотя уже всё проверил. В Swing пока мало опыта.

```
public void initUI() {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame(MovingCircle.class.getSimpleName());
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setLayout(null);
    JPanel circle = new JPanel() {
       public void paint(Graphics graphics) {
             graphics.drawOval(200, 200, 150, 150);
             graphics.setColor(Color.black);
          }
       };

        frame.add(circle);
        frame.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        xCircle = getNextSpeed() * (random.nextBoolean() ? 1 : -1);
        yCircle = getNextSpeed() * (random.nextBoolean() ? 1 : -1);
        Timer t = new Timer(1000 / STEPS_OF_IMAGE_PER_SECOND, (ActionEvent e) -> {
            xcCircle += xCircle;
            ycCircle += yCircle;
            if (xcCircle + circle.getWidth() > frame.getContentPane().getWidth()) {
                xcCircle = frame.getContentPane().getWidth() - circle.getWidth();
                xCircle = -getNextSpeed();
            } else if (xcCircle < 0) {
                xcCircle = 0;
                xCircle = getNextSpeed();
            }
            if (ycCircle + circle.getHeight() > frame.getContentPane().getHeight()) {
                ycCircle = frame.getContentPane().getHeight() - circle.getHeight();
                yCircle = -getNextSpeed();
            } else if (ycCircle < 0) {
                ycCircle = 0;
                yCircle = getNextSpeed();
            }
            circle.setLocation((int) xcCircle, (int) ycCircle);
        });
        frame.setVisible(true);
        t.start();
    }
```

Comment: Уберите `frame.setLayout(null);`

Comment: Спасибо, помогло. Только с движением что-то не то теперь. Буду разбираться.

Comment: Прекрасно. Удачи